# Why is the escape syntax different between two Javascript functions: search vs replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, replace, escaping

Use this string as example

```
s = "a(b"
```

These two work as expected

```
s.search("\\(")
1

s.replace("\(", "")
"ab"
```

But these don't

```
s.search("\(")
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group

s.replace("\\(", "")
"a(b"
```

Huh? Why does search require one more escape than replace?

Also, shouldn't string input give a literal search, instead of being interpreted as a regexp? In theory, I shouldn't have to use escape characters at all.

Comment: The error message explains everything. `s.search` treats the argument as a regex pattern (so, the special chars must be escaped with a literal backslash), and `s.replace` treats the input as a string.

Comment: _“ String.prototype.search (regexp): If regexp is not an object whose [[Class]] property is "RegExp", it is replaced with the result of the
expression new RegExp(regexp).”_ - http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string literal `'\('` is equivalent to `'('`, so you’re not really escaping anything at all with it.

`String#search` always interprets its argument as a regular expression; if you want to find an exact match, use `String#indexOf`.

```
> s.indexOf('(')
1
```

`s.replace` accepts either a string or a regular expression. You’re giving it the string `(` in the first case (so it replaces the first opening parenthesis it sees) and `\(` in the second (not in the string, so it replaces nothing).